# Editor > Canvas > Live Autoresizing missing in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, xcode7, designer

I am using old autosizing constraints and want to see live how it will behave like in old days but somehow I don't see this option anymore and it is not autoresizing view when I resize it in editor... So it is not possible anymore ?

Ok maybe I am not too clear... but thats because I thought this is so obvious and used a lot feature of xcode editor...

So I have this on my screen
[image]
Before when I dragged corner of view that has size freeform view resized and all view inside resized also according to autosizing layout constraint. Autolayout is disabled in xib. It was possible to turn it on or off in menu Editor > Canvas > Live Autoresizing.. Now there is no such option. Is it possible still somehow ?

Comment: Do you mean `Editor > Simulated Screens` in Storyboard?

Comment: Simulated screens don't do anything here... There are just some options like iphone 5.5 ... and it is doing nothing , also I don't think this is same as  Canvas > Live Autoresizing... I updated question to be more clear...

Comment: @ReneDohan Hi Rene, have you ever find a way to test the constraint "live" from interface builder with xcode 7 ?

Comment: No no , it looks like we have to live without this now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I cam back to my own unanswered question, just accidentally I found that live auto resizing(old style) in editor works, just little but differently. When you change size of view in Size inspector by those up and down buttons, it works like old days...

[image]